# Mathematical background required to learn about sheaves

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, sheaf-theory

Due to my interest in type theory (and higher type theory), I have found that learning about sheaves might be useful (for, e.g., sheaf models of type theories). There is Kashiwara and Schapira's *Categories and Sheaves*, but that seems way out of reach for me at the moment.

My background includes some category theory and a little bit of algebraic topology, and I'll probably have to read more of both. However, what *else* do I need? Perhaps learn some algebraic geometry, or higher category theory?

Comment: I don't think you need anything too fancy to learn about sheaves. I would recommend Mac Lane and Moerdijk's book Sheaves in Geometry and Logic.

Answer (score 2):

Good references to learn about sheaves are :

1)Sheaf Theory (Graduate Texts in Mathematics,1997)
by Glen E. Bredon .
2) Cohomology of Sheaves , by Birger Iversen (Universitext, Springer).

Comment: I forgot to mention the classical reference : Topologie algébrique et Théorie des faisceaux  by  Roger Godement  (Hermann Editeurs, 2006).